# Copying a parent element to be displayed in a modal box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link which I want to display a modal dialog box, containing a headline and a copy of the parent element of the clicked link.

```
$('#link').live('click',function(){
    container = $(this).parents(".container")[0];
    message = $("<h2>You clicked on this.</h2>" + container);
    message.find(".foo, .bar, .lorem").remove();

    console.log(message[0]);
    // code for displaying the box using message[0]
});
```

I also have to filter out certain children of the container element.

However, this (being my fourth attempt at it after dabbling with `clone()` and `insertAfter()` for a while) does not work. It only displays the `<h2>`, with no sight of the copy of the parent element.

Obviously the original parent element still visible on the page behind the modal should not be affected.

What's wrong here?

Comment: You should use on instead of outdated live.

Comment: Show us the code on how you display the modal box, and explain where the <h2> should go.

Comment: I'm using [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/), so the code is `$.modal(message, {options: "foo", ... })`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '#link', function(){
    var container = $(this).closest(".container").clone(true);
        container.find(".foo, .bar, .lorem").remove();
    var message = $("<h2>You clicked on this.</h2>").add(container);

    $('#modalID').append(message);

    console.log(message);
});
```

Comment: I did something similar originally, but ran into `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'find'`, so I thought I was failing at `.clone()`. Ran into it again here, any idea what's up?

Comment: @EmphramStavanger - I have no idea why the cloning does'nt work, I tried replicating it in a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DEC6s/), and it seems to work just fine ?

Comment: Fixed it by changing the variable name, I guess there was some conflict somewhere... It's late at night... :P

Comment: Yes it's late, and always happy to help !

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you contact the line message = `$("<h2>You clicked on this.</h2>" + container);` because this is not the correct way to concatenate strings

Like this

```
message = "<h2>You clicked on this.</h2>" + container;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
message = $("<h2>You clicked on this.</h2>" + container);
```

would be the answer to "What's wrong here?". `container` is a DOM element, and the plus operator won't work. I guess you want to do something like

```
var message = $(this).closest(".container").clone(true);
message.prepend("<h2>You clicked on this.</h2>");
message.find(".foo, .bar, .lorem").remove();

// then take the message container and view it as a modal box
```